# ¿Qué paso puedo tomar para arreglar la advertencia de "Raw use of parameterized class 'Class' "?

Tags: java, genericos

En el siguiente programa, tengo la clase `Cow`, la clase `Dragon` derivada de la clase `Cow` y la clase `IceDragon` derivada de la clase `Dragon`.

También existe la clase `HeiferGenerator`, responsable de crear una matriz que contiene instancias de `Cow`, `Dragon` y `IceDragon`.

Sin embargo, en la clase `HeifeferGenerator`, recibo la advertencia "*Raw use of parameterized class 'Class'*" en la línea:

```
private static final Class[] dragonTypes = {Dragon.class, IceDragon.class};
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para corregir esta advertencia?

```
// Cow class

public class Cow {

    // Declaring attributes name and image
    private final String name;
    private String image;

    // Constructor to create a new Cow object with parameter name
    public Cow (String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = null;
    }

    // Accessor to return the name of the cow
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // Accessor to return the image used to display the cow after the message
    public String getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    // Mutator to set the image used to display the cow after the message
    public void setImage(String _image) {
        this.image = _image;
    }
}
enter code here

// Dragon class derived from the Cow class

public class Dragon extends Cow {
    // Constructor to create a new Dragon object with parameters name and image
    public Dragon (String name, String image) {
        super(name);
        setImage(image);
    }

    // Function to return true for the default Dragon type
    public boolean canBreatheFire() {
        return true;
    }
}



// IceDragon class derived from the Dragon class

public class IceDragon extends Dragon {
    // Constructor to create a new IceDragon object with parameters name and image
    public IceDragon (String name, String image) {
        super(name, image);
    }

    // Function to return false for the IceDragon type
    public boolean canBreatheFire() {
        return false;
    }
}
  


import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class HeiferGenerator
{
    public static Cow[] getCows()
    {
        if (cows == null)
        {
            cows = new Cow[cowNames.length + dragonNames.length];

            // Add the "regular" cows
            for (int index = 0; index < cowNames.length; index++)
            {
                cows[index] = new Cow(cowNames[index]);
                cows[index].setImage(quoteLines + cowImages[index]);
            }

            // Add the dragons
            for (int offset = cowNames.length, index = 0; index < dragonNames.length; index++)
            {
                try
                {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Constructor<Dragon> constructor = dragonTypes[index].getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
                    cows[offset + index] = constructor.newInstance(dragonNames[index], quoteLines + dragonImage);
                }
                catch (Exception ignored) { }
            }
        }

        return cows;
    }

    // Hard-coded values for some of the cows
    private static final String[] cowNames = { "heifer", "kitteh" };

    private static final String quoteLines =        "       \\\n" +
            "        \\\n" +
            "         \\\n";

    private static final String[] cowImages = { "        ^__^\n" +
            "        (oo)\\_______\n" +
            "        (__)\\       )\\/\\\n" +
            "            ||----w |\n" +
            "            ||     ||\n",


            "       (\"`-'  '-/\") .___..--' ' \"`-._\n" +
                    "         ` *_ *  )    `-.   (      ) .`-.__. `)\n" +
                    "         (_Y_.) ' ._   )   `._` ;  `` -. .-'\n" +
                    "      _.. `--'_..-_/   /--' _ .' ,4\n" +
                    "   ( i l ),-''  ( l i),'  ( ( ! .-'\n"
    };

    private static final  String[] dragonNames = { "dragon", "ice-dragon" };
    private static final Class[] dragonTypes = {Dragon.class, Dragon.class};


    private static final String dragonImage =     "           |\\___/|       /\\  //|\\\\\n" +
            "           /0  0  \\__   /  \\// | \\ \\\n" +
            "          /     /  \\/_ /   //  |  \\  \\\n" +
            "          \\_^_\\'/   \\/_   //   |   \\   \\\n" +
            "          //_^_/     \\/_ //    |    \\    \\\n" +
            "       ( //) |        \\ //     |     \\     \\\n" +
            "     ( / /) _|_ /   )   //     |      \\     _\\\n" +
            "   ( // /) '/,_ _ _/  ( ; -.   |    _ _\\.-~       .-~~~^-.\n" +
            " (( / / )) ,-{        _      `.|.-~-.          .~         `.\n" +
            "(( // / ))  '/\\      /                ~-. _.-~      .-~^-.  \\\n" +
            "(( /// ))      `.   {            }                 /      \\  \\\n" +
            " (( / ))     .----~-.\\        \\-'               .~         \\  `.   __\n" +
            "            ///.----..>        \\            _ -~            `.  ^-`  \\\n" +
            "              ///-._ _ _ _ _ _ _}^ - - - - ~                   `-----'\n";

      private static Cow[] cows = null;

  }
```

<sub>Traducción del [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891186/)</sub>

<sub>[Traducción en portugués](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/561961/que-passo-posso-tomar-para-corrigir-o-aviso-raw-use-of-parameterized-class-cla)</sub>

Comment: Si de casualidad no te fueran suficientes vacas y dragones has otra pregunta y con gusto te mostramos como generar mas de dos veces el limite de long de mi solucion actual :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La advertencia se trata de que ¡podrían accidentalmente haber vacas entre los tipos de dragones! Vaya desastre... No quisiera que mis vacas se mezclaran con dragones (aunque se afirme que los dragones son subtipos vacunos)

El uso de genéricos con arreglos es algo muy batalloso, la mayoría prefiere usar alguna clase del API de colecciones de java y convertir a arreglo posteriormente.

Yo te doy otra opción... Las siempre confiables enumeraciones.
Si bien las enumeraciones básicas solo tienen una lista de palabras que equivalen a enteros empezando desde el cero, puedes asociarlas a tanta cantidad de cosas como quieras agregando un constructor. En nuestro caso sería así:

```
public enum DragonTypes {
    DRAGON(Dragon.class),
    ICE_DRAGON(IceDragon.class);
    private Class<? extends Dragon> type;

    DragonTypes(Class<? extends Dragon> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Class<? extends Dragon> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Como verás, el `?` indica cualquier clase, lo cual suena bien pero no es suficientemente específico, así que le decimos que cualquier cosa que extienda a Dragon para que así no se nos cuele una vaca ni por asomo.

Para obtener todos los valores como un arreglo tenemos el bonito método `values()`, así que remplazando en el código pondríamos

```
private static DragonTypes[] dragonTypes = DragonTypes.values();
```

pero esto no nos daría un arreglo de clases, sino un arreglo de tipo de dragones... Afortunadamente para eso pusimos un siempre-práctico *getter*, así que en la lista de constructores pondremos

```
Constructor<? extends Dragon> constructor = dragonTypes[index].getType().getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
```

y magia magia magia! Ahora ya no es un constructor de únicamente Dragones... Sino de dragones y sus subtipos.

### Ventajas

Como verás, las ventajas de este enfoque son que:

- es mantenible
- suficientemente abstracto
- no es una solución tan rebuscada
- no necesitas aprender demasiado comparado con otras soluciones
  (como por ejemplo usar el [service loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), el   [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html) de spring)
- no necesitas ninguna librería sino que basta con java se (a diferencia de por ejemplo usar una solución con [reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)).

### Extra

Como mi solución se ven como dos líneas y tu programa está igual con muy pocas vacas y dragones, podemos cambiar el código para soportar tener muchísimas más vacas y dragones de la siguiente manera:

Extraemos el proceso de generación de imágenes usando una interfaz y sus respectivas implementaciones

```
public interface ImageGenerator {
    String quoteLines = "       \\\n"
            + "        \\\n"
            + "         \\\n";

    String generateCowImage();
}
```

para imágenes de vacas

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CowImageGenerator implements ImageGenerator {
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public String generateCowImage() {
        return quoteLines + cowImages[random.nextInt(1)];
    }

    private static final String[] cowImages = {"        ^__^\n"
            + "        (oo)\\_______\n"
            + "        (__)\\       )\\/\\\n"
            + "            ||----w |\n"
            + "            ||     ||\n",
            "       (\"`-'  '-/\") .___..--' ' \"`-._\n"
                    + "         ` *_ *  )    `-.   (      ) .`-.__. `)\n"
                    + "         (_Y_.) ' ._   )   `._` ;  `` -. .-'\n"
                    + "      _.. `--'_..-_/   /--' _ .' ,4\n"
                    + "   ( i l ),-''  ( l i),'  ( ( ! .-'\n"
    };
}
```

y para imágenes de dragones

```
public class DragonImageGenerator implements ImageGenerator {
    @Override
    public String generateCowImage() {
        return quoteLines + dragonImage;
    }

    private static final String dragonImage = "           |\\___/|       /\\  //|\\\\\n"
            + "           /0  0  \\__   /  \\// | \\ \\\n"
            + "          /     /  \\/_ /   //  |  \\  \\\n"
            + "          \\_^_\\'/   \\/_   //   |   \\   \\\n"
            + "          //_^_/     \\/_ //    |    \\    \\\n"
            + "       ( //) |        \\ //     |     \\     \\\n"
            + "     ( / /) _|_ /   )   //     |      \\     _\\\n"
            + "   ( // /) '/,_ _ _/  ( ; -.   |    _ _\\.-~       .-~~~^-.\n"
            + " (( / / )) ,-{        _      `.|.-~-.          .~         `.\n"
            + "(( // / ))  '/\\      /                ~-. _.-~      .-~^-.  \\\n"
            + "(( /// ))      `.   {            }                 /      \\  \\\n"
            + " (( / ))     .----~-.\\        \\-'               .~         \\  `.   __\n"
            + "            ///.----..>        \\            _ -~            `.  ^-`  \\\n"
            + "              ///-._ _ _ _ _ _ _}^ - - - - ~                   `-----'\n";
}
```

Le metemos faker para generar los nombres y pasamos la lógica a stream.

```
import com.github.javafaker.Faker;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class HeiferGenerator {

    private static Faker faker = new Faker();
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static ImageGenerator cowImageGenerator = new CowImageGenerator();
    private static ImageGenerator dragonImageGenerator = new DragonImageGenerator();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("cows:" + Arrays.toString(getCows().toArray()));
    }


    public static Stream<Cow> getCows() {


        int cowsToGenerate = random.nextInt(100);
        int dragonsToGenerate = random.nextInt(100);
        return Stream.concat(
                // Add the "regular" cows
                Stream.generate(() -> {
                    Cow aCow = new Cow(faker.name().firstName());
                    aCow.setImage(cowImageGenerator.generateCowImage());
                    return aCow;
                }).limit(cowsToGenerate),

                // Add the dragons
                Stream.generate(() ->
                {
                    try {
                        return dragonTypes[random.nextInt(dragonTypes.length)].getType().getConstructor(String.class, String.class).newInstance(faker.ancient().primordial(), dragonImageGenerator.generateCowImage());
                    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException |
                             NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }).limit(dragonsToGenerate)
        );

    }

    private static DragonTypes[] dragonTypes = DragonTypes.values();

}
```

Como habrás visto, le puse que aleatoriamente genere hasta 100 vacas y hasta 100 dragones, pero puedes modificar los números hasta el máximo valor de long (y eso tal vez sea demasiado... para tu computadora.... no para la cantidad de vacas y dragones que uno pudiera querer en su mundo de fantasía)